# How to fetch values from one table and insert the same values in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using two buttons "Fetch" and "Submit" in the same page. When I click "Fetch" button am getting the values from one table[ticketgeneration] and display in the form, and fetch is working fine. When I tried to insert the fetch records to another table[details] the records is not inserting.

```
HTML PART
<div class="col-sm-3">
             <center><input type="submit" name="fetch" id="fetch" class="btn btn-primary" value="Fetch Records" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;float:right;"></center>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
                <center><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;float:left;"></center>
        </div>
```

```
PHP PART
if (isset($_POST['fetch'])) {
       $ticketid1 = $_POST['tid'];
        $sel = "select * from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sel);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        
    }
```

The above code is fetching the values from "ticketgeneration" table and display in the textbox

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="custname" id="custname" value="<?php echo $row['customer_name'];?>">
```

When I tried to insert the fetched values to other table [details] it is not inserting.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ticketgendate = $_POST['date'];
       $ticketid = $row['ticket_id'];
        $customername = $row['customer_name'];
...
$ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,...)values (('$ticketgendate','$ticketid','$customername',...)";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
```

am I missing condition somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data insert from one table to another table used this query.

`$query = 'insert into table_name (col1, col2, columnList....) select col1, col2, columnList... from table_name where ticket_id = $id';`

You can add other column in select statement, just mention column name in insert query statement.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks Kiran.. so i need to use like this ...`$ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem....start_time,end_time,reviewed_by,comments) values (...'$starttime','$endtime',' $reviewedby','$comments') select date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem_reported_by,contact_no,mail_id,.. from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1';` My working url  - https://sampledemos.online/callreports/details.php. Upto calltype am fetching records from one table and after call type am inserting both fetched and new entry values in the table - details

Comment: Yaa you can change insert || select query according to your requirement. -

Comment: Okay Thanks... @kiran values are inserted.. I got all the fetch values and assigned to  $_POST[] and used normal insert query ... Thanks for your valuable time....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below query to insert data in your case.
Use only $ticketid1 to insert data.

```
$ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,...) select date,ticket_id,customer_name,... from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1'";
```

And then run your query, it will insert selected data directly without doing extra code.

Comment: Thanks N.S. from customer_name to call_type am fetching the records from one table and inserting the same with your code and for the remaining fields in the form I need to insert the field values, what I need to do... In my form both fetch and insert needs to be done...

Comment: You can add other fields in select statement, just mention field name in insert query statement and its value in select statement which you did earlier in your quetion. ex. insert into details (date, ticket_id, ... , xyz)  select date, ticket_id, ... , '$xyz' from ..

Comment: Thanks N.S is my query syntax correct - `$ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem....start_time,end_time,reviewed_by,comments) values (...'$starttime','$endtime',' $reviewedby','$comments') select date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem_reported_by,contact_no,mail_id,.. from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1';`  My working url  - https://sampledemos.online/callreports/details.php. Upto calltype am fetching records from one table and after call type am inserting both fetched and new entry values in the table - details

Comment: No need to use values here. $ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem....start_time,end_time,reviewed_by,comments)  select date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem_reported_by,contact_no,mail_id,.., '$starttime','$endtime',' $reviewedby','$comments' from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1';

Comment: Okay Thanks... @N.S values are inserted.. I got all the fetch values and assigned to  $_POST[] and used normal insert query ... Thanks for your valuable time....